# Convert array into list for MultiLabelBinarizer

Tags: python, arrays, list, scikit-learn

I have the following array : `"['book', 'read']" "['cup', 'drink']"` etc, and I would like to convert it into a list that would allow me to apply [MultiLabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html).

Currently it is either giving me individual characters or outputting just 0s.

```
Y = train_labels.iloc[:, 0].values
values = np.array(Y)

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=("drink","cup","book", "read"))
output = mlb.fit_transform(values)
print(output)
```

Expected Results:

```
[0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0]
```

Actual Results:

```
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: Print the contents of `'values'`

Comment: ["['book', 'read']" "['book', 'read']" "['book', 'read']" .... And I am also getting this: unknown class(es) [' ', "'", ',', '[', ']', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'i', 'k', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 'u'] will be ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to pay attention to the proper format of the input to `MultiLabelBinarizer`.

> y : iterable of iterables
>   A set of labels (any orderable and hashable object) for each sample.

**Proof:**

```
txt = [['book', 'read'],['cup', 'drink']]
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=("drink","cup","book", "read"))
mlb.fit_transform(txt)
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Please, let us know if this solves your problem.

**Note on data format**

Should you insist your data is in an array like you specified in your post:

```
arr = ["['book', 'read']","['cup', 'drink']"]
```

the following code snippet will transform it to the proper format:

```
import re
[["".join(re.findall("\w",f)) for f in lst] for lst in [s.split(",") for s in arr]]
[['book', 'read'], ['cup', 'drink']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

You can convert your array using `ast.literal_eval()`

```
arr = ["['book', 'read']","['cup', 'drink']","['book', 'read']","['book', 'read']"]

import ast 
X = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in arr]

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=("drink","cup","book", "read"))
output = mlb.fit_transform(X)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1]]
```